# Issue with toggle icon

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap accordion element to hide and show content.
And i also added font-awesome icon next to accordion title with toggle icon functionality when area of accordion is expanded.Now the problem is that when i click the title the icon will not toggle but if i click on the icon it-self it works just fine, but i also want the same functionality with title also.

This is the code

```js
  $(".fa").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-minus");
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse1">
            Big <i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
          sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
          commodo consequat.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance for your great efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to trigger the click event to the big element and then toggle the class of the i element.
p.s i added a class .click to the element where the click event should happen.

```js
  $(".click").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass("fa-minus");
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
  
<body>
  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading ">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse1" class = "click">
                          Big <i class="click fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                        commodo consequat.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
  
  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm bro
Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: One small problem is that if you click anywhere except text and icon,
that icon is also toggling.
How to fix that any idea??

Comment: i updated the answer. You can do it by removing .click class from the element and place it to the text (a tag) and + (i tag)

Comment: Works just perfect.
Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse1" class="accorionId">
                          Big <i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                        commodo consequat.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    </div>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".accorionId").on("click", function(){
    $($(this).find('.fa')).toggleClass("fa-minus");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check its working now
[codePan](http://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/mENoVY)

Comment: Can please tell me how can i attach CodePan or JSFiddle link here?
I'm new to Stack Overflow and don't know how to put this link.
I tried but it says you can't attach link directly.

Comment: You have to write any word like codepen then select that codepen and attach respective URL to that word from code pen and jsfiddle and add simple

Answer (score 0):

Move script to head which is in body now

```js
  $(".fa").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-minus");
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse1">
                                Big <i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
                              </a>
                        </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                              minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                              commodo consequat.
                        </div>      
                  </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you changed? Explain what the user has done wrong, so he may learn from it ;).

Comment: When you are clicking on Big the also it should get changed

Comment: Yes when we are clicking on edit then also we toggling is happening. I saw error that $ is not defined so moved script to head which was in body

Answer (score 0):

please give it a try

```js
  $(".panel-heading").on("click", function(){
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass("fa-minus");
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
  
<body>
  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse1">
                          Big <i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                        commodo consequat.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
  
  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for all your accordion Tabs:

```js
  $(".panel-title a").on("click", function(){
    $(this).children(".fa").toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Add the below code to so you can click anywhere on the title and the accordion will work. -->
<style>
  .panel-title a{
     display:block;
  }
</style>
</head>
  
<body>
  
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapse1">
                          Big <i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
                        </a>
                      </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
                        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                        commodo consequat.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
  
  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```